# partitioning column

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a database with a few tables in it, one of which is quite a big. I decided to partition it. So after studying how I should I do that, I decided to do it by a wizard. In the section which I had to select a column for partitioning, I noticed that just a part of the columns of a table are visible there are fields for which user defined type are not visible for selecting as the partitioning column. For example I have a field named "Date_Register" with Type "Date_Short:smalldatetime". "Date_Short:smalldatetime" is a user defined type with the following specification:

```
Name: Date_Short
Data type: smalldatetime
precision: 16
storage : 9 byte
```

is it possible to select Date_Register as partitioning column?

Comment: What is the actual definition of your user defined type? `smalldatetime` is 4 bytes not 9.

Comment: you are right , but this what is in it and it is working for years, I can not change it at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx)

> input_parameter_type Is the data type of the column used for
>   partitioning. All data types are valid for use as partitioning
>   columns, **except** text, ntext, image, xml, timestamp, varchar(max),
>   nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), **alias data types, or CLR user-defined
>   data types.**

So looks like you're out of luck.

I'm curious about the definition of `DateShort` anyway though and whether it in fact adds any value over just using `smalldatetime` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Martin is right, but a workaround might be to add a computed column casting your udt as something acceptable as a partitioning key.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD computed_col AS CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, your_udt_col) PERSISTED
```

You could use a different data type, I'm using small date time because that's how your udt is defined.

[Background here.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/potential-problems-partitioning/)